# some part is getting cut in Xcode simulator for ipad retina? using React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am new to react native I just started it, After installing react native in the terminal and I created projects according to that explained in the docs.
When running the project in the Xcode simulator I find some issues I don't to how to rectify it can anyone help me. here are the images of my simulator
it is for iPhone 6[image]

the second one is for iPad retina
[image]

when simulating iPad retina last part is cutting how to solve it. any solution is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Because your screen is designed for iPhone 5 or 6.

iPad retina support only iPhone 4 screen size in emulation.